# Why is NSImage dragging but not dropping?

Tags: swift, cocoa, drag-and-drop, nsimage

MyView has user-provided text, images, etc. Goal is for user to be able to drag an image from there to wherever an image can go. Code is customized from GitHub sample. Every part of code works as expected--all the funcs from the NSDraggingSource protocol are called when expected--and the dragged image looks exactly as it should as it drags around. But there's no drop in any destination where, for example, I can drop images dragged from other apps. What am I missing that's preventing the drop?

```
    class MyView: NSView, NSDraggingSource {
var mouseDownEvent: NSEvent?

override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    super.drawRect(dirtyRect)
}

func draggingSession(session: NSDraggingSession, sourceOperationMaskForDraggingContext context: NSDraggingContext) -> NSDragOperation {
    return .Copy
}

func draggingSession(session: NSDraggingSession, endedAtPoint screenPoint: NSPoint, operation: NSDragOperation) {
}

func draggingSession(session: NSDraggingSession, willBeginAtPoint screenPoint: NSPoint) {
}

func draggingSession(session: NSDraggingSession, movedToPoint screenPoint: NSPoint) {
}

override func mouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
    self.mouseDownEvent = theEvent
}

override func mouseDragged(theEvent: NSEvent) {
    let mouseDown = self.mouseDownEvent!.locationInWindow
    var point: NSPoint = theEvent.locationInWindow
    point = anotherView!.convertPoint(point, toView: nil)

    if CGRectContainsPoint(someObject.rect, point) {
        let image = (someObject.contents as! NSImage)
        let draggingItem = NSDraggingItem(pasteboardWriter: image)
        let draggingFrameOrigin = convertPoint(mouseDown, fromView: nil)
        let draggingFrame = NSRect(origin: draggingFrameOrigin, size: image.size).offsetBy(dx: -image.size.width / 2, dy: -image.size.height / 2)
        draggingItem.draggingFrame = draggingFrame
        draggingItem.imageComponentsProvider = {
            let component = NSDraggingImageComponent(key: NSDraggingImageComponentIconKey)
            component.contents = image
            component.frame = NSRect(origin: NSPoint(), size: draggingFrame.size)
            return [component]
        }
        beginDraggingSessionWithItems([draggingItem], event: mouseDownEvent!, source: self)
    }
}
```

}

Might it have to do with dragging from an `NSView` and not an `NSImageView`? I supply `image` to `draggingItem`, but is that just for the dragging visual and not the content being dropped?

Thank you!

Comment: `NSDraggingSource` is for dragging, implement `NSDraggingDestination` for dropping. Don't forget to call `registerForDraggedTypes`.

Comment: I already have dropping working within my app for stuff dragged from other apps. For example, I can drag an image from a web page or text from Notes or TextEdit and drop it into MyView. What's not working is the images dragged from MyView being dropped into Finder or other apps that accept dropped stuff. Hope that clarifies what I've not yet figured out. Thanks!

Comment: I can drop the image in TextEdit.

Comment: Hmmmm, thanks for that info. Good to know this works for someone. I tried eliminating the destination/`registerForDraggedTypes` code (it's part of an `NSWindow` subclass) in case that interfered, but still no success. I drag an image to TextEdit, and it just rubberbands back to the source when I drop it. Wonder what other code I have that could be getting in the way...